# Filtering dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

[image]

How do i filter out rows in a dataframe Based on values between 2 columns. Please refer the image. My expected result would be the rows between TRUE in Column A and TRUE in Column B. 
As it is highlighted in the image the expected result would be two dataframes where first dataframe df1 should have rows from index 2 to 6 and second dataframe df2 should have rows from index 10 to 16

Answer (score 2):

Since you require rows between the two conditions.

```
df = pd.read_excel("your_excel.xls")
start_index = df[df["A"] == "TRUE"].index[0]
end_index = df[df["B"] == "TRUE"].index[0]
df = df.iloc[start_index : end_index]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'other':range(9),
                   'A':[True ,False, False ,False, False ,True, False, False, False],
                   'B':[False,False,False,True,False,False,False,True,False]})


   other      A      B
0      0   True  False
1      1  False  False
2      2  False  False
3      3  False   True
4      4  False  False
5      5   True  False
6      6  False  False
7      7  False   True
8      8  False  False
```

---

**Solution**

```
df2 = df[df['A'].cumsum().ge(1)]
m1 = ~df2[['A','B']].any(axis = 1)
m2=(df2['A'].add(df2['B']).cumsum()%2).eq(1)
#m2=(df2['A'].add(df2['B']).cumsum()%2) #It could be enough
df_filtered = df2.loc[m1 & m2]
print(df_filtered)
   other      A      B
1      1  False  False
2      2  False  False
6      6  False  False
```

Comment: Nice masking. I was doing something more or less the same.

Comment: Thanks @Celius Stingher

Answer (score 0):

If its a pandas dataframe then the following might help you:

```
result = df[(df['A']== 'TRUE' ) | (df['B'] == 'TRUE')]
```

Comment: OP is interested in keeping the rows between the TRUE values. Furthermore we can see TRUE/FALSE are strings, not booleans. The result should drop only the 0 and 8 row.

Comment: Where do yo usee True/False are strings?

Comment: They are written `TRUE` and `FALSE`, boolean objects are `True` and `False` in python.